# php4 decode string to display as html

Tags: php, html, xml

I'm very new to PHP and I have a small task of displaying a class list from an XML file.  I have managed to figure that part out that took longer than expected.  I'm running into some descriptions that have html characters that are not displaying on my page.  I have tried numerous ways and nothing seems to work for me.  Please take a look and let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
    $bb = "&lt;P&gt;Dont spend another day &lt;B&gt;manually&lt;/B&gt; filtering information from your spreadsheets.&lt;/P&gt;";        
    $a = htmlentities($bb);
    $b = html_entity_decode($a);


    echo $book['PRODUCTID']." - ".$book['PRODUCTNAME']." - ".$b."<BR/><BR/>";
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get rid of

```
    $a = htmlentities($bb);
```

just use

```
    $b = html_entity_decode($bb);
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this will help:

str_replace(array("&lt;", "&gt;"), array("<", ">"), $bb);

that should solve the problem